# I'm planning on switching job in my home country while waiting for H1B 2018 lottery results. Will this create any challenges on the Visa interview?

Tags: h1-visa

I’m with company **A** (my current work) for more than couple years now, and now I have an H1B petition with company **B**. If I don’t get selected on lottery, my contract with **B** ends, and I can re-apply with B next year.

Now while waiting for the H1B lottery results, I have a good local job offer from **C** (with no H1B, this is just a local employment offer in my home country). If I resign with **A** to join **C** this May/June, will this local move affect my Visa interview? (assuming I get selected in the lottery).

Will it show I have weak ties in my company? Any other challenge I might face on the Visa interview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR - Switching jobs shouldn't make much (if any) difference to your H-1B visa interview.

The interview for an H-1B goes a little differently to that for a B-1/B-2 visa.
I know because I've done both.

The premise of a B-1/B-2 interview is that the interviewer is supposed to start off assuming that you intend to immigrate to USA illegally - and its your responsibility to convince them otherwise.
But since the H-1B is recognized as a 'dual intent' visa (in other words there's a path to permanent residency through an H-1B) you don't need to show strong ties 'back home' - in fact you barely need to show any ties at all.

My original H-1B interview a few years ago and the renewal last year were virtually non-events.
In the first interview I was asked a little about the company I would be working for and the work I'd be doing, but since the interviewer can't really be qualified in every one of the 100,000's of different professions you could be performing the questions aren't too deep.
For my renewal, since I had just changed to a different H-1B sponsor company, I was asked a little about the difference between the old job and new - but nothing unusual or particularly probing.

You do need to be prepared to answer these questions accurately and confidently though.
There are plenty of people and companies who try to scam the H-1B system to get into the USA illegally and you need to avoid giving this impression.